# TSQL: Find required missing records

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need  a query to find Inspection/Component that did not get a "Rating 6" record. I'll be inserting new records so that all Inspection/Component have a "Rating 6" record along with what ever other ratings they may have.

Consider the following data: 57646, 57652 and 57657 are **not** correct because they are missing their Rating 6 record. In this data example, these three should be the only Inspection/Component returned by the query.

```
InspectionID  ComponentID     RatingTypeID
138           57646           10
138           57647           6
138           57647           2
138           57648           6
138           57649           6
138           57650           6
138           57651           10
138           57651           6
138           57652           10
138           57653           6
138           57654           6
138           57655           6
138           57656           6
138           57657           10
```

Comment: Just curious, if all of these combinations need this rating type, what purpose does it serve? Seems like this should be handled by the application or other query logic if records are missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable A
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM YourTable
                 WHERE InspectionID = A.InspectionID  
                 AND ComponentID = A.ComponentID
                 AND RatingTypeID = 6)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT A.InspectionID FROM MyTable AS A
LEFT OUTER JOIN MyTable AS B
ON A.InspectionID = B.InspectionID AND B.RatingTypeID = 6
WHERE B.InspectionID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from YOURTABLE where componentId not in (select componentId from YOURTABLE where RatingTypeId=6)
```